# How do I write version files for pyinstaller 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert my python script to an exe and everything went well until I added a version file, it threw this error and I don't know what it means. I've seen different posts about version files and I've tried them all and I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
exec(text, spec_namespace)
File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 407, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 178, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 496, in assemble
versioninfo.SetVersion(tmpnm, self.versrsrc)
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\versioninfo.py", line 557, in SetVersion
win32api.UpdateResource(hdst, pefile.RESOURCE_TYPE['RT_VERSION'], 1, vs.toRaw())
File "c:\users\afro\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\versioninfo.py", line 160, in toRaw
nm = pywintypes.Unicode(u'VS_VERSION_INFO')
TypeError: argument 1 (impossible<bad format char>)
```

and here's my version file:

```
VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
    filevers=(1, 0, 0, 0),
    prodvers=(1, 0, 0, 0),
    mask=0x3f,
    flags=0x0,
    OS=0x40004,
    fileType=0x1,
    subtype=0x0,
    date=(0, 0)
    ),
  kids=[
    StringFileInfo(
      [
    StringTable(
        u'040904B0',
        [StringStruct(u'CompanyName', u'getSERIES'),
        StringStruct(u'FileDescription', u'get it'),
        StringStruct(u'FileVersion', u'6.1.7601.17514    (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)'),
        StringStruct(u'InternalName', u'getSERIES'),
        StringStruct(u'LegalCopyright', u'HA corporation. All rights reserved.'),
        StringStruct(u'OriginalFilename', u'getSERIES.Exe'),
        StringStruct(u'ProductName', u'getSERIES'),
        StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'1, 0, 0, 0')])
    ]), 
    VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1033, 1200])])
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version file should be good enough. The problem is in PyInstaller's versioninfo.py which is probably has no Python3 support at this time.
As a simple workaround, you can try to use a resource editor (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows) to add version info to your application.
Related pyinstaller issue for additional information: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1347.